# Error deploying Node app on render.com: "The engine 'node' is incompatible with this module"

Tags: node.js, render.com

## **Error deploying Node app on render.com: "The engine 'node' is incompatible with this module"**

I am trying to deploy my Node.js application on render.com, but I encountered the following

```
error mongoose@7.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.20.1". Got "14.17.0"
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  },
  "name": "shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I am trying to deploy my Node.js application on render.com, but I encountered the following

```
error mongoose@7.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.20.1". Got "14.17.0"
```

Comment: So the Mongoose library expects a higher Node version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can update your package.json file by adding the "engines" field and specifying the required Node.js version. Here's what you need to do:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=14.20.1"
}
```

in my case:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  },
  "name": "shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
 "engines": {
      "node": ">=14.20.1"
    },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

This informs the hosting platform that your application requires at least Node.js version 14.20.1 or higher to run properly.

Make sure to save the changes to your package.json file. If you're using a version control system like Git, commit and push the updated file to your repository.

By adding the "engines" field and specifying the required Node.js version, the hosting platform should now use a compatible version when deploying your application. This should resolve the "The engine 'node' is incompatible with this module" error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

add Build Command - `yarn --ignore-engines` on [render.com](https://render.com)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQDAo.png

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34741174)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do the command :

```
nvm use 14.{your_version}
```

Maybe you have to run before :

```
nvm install 14.{your_version}
```